# Valor datepicker custom locale

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I am using Angular2 with typescript and Valor datepicker. Datepicker does not come with the required locale. I searched around and found that the required js file that has the locale info in, is present in momentjs git repository. How can I use that js file?

I tried to replicate the way angular does it in the ngx-bootstrap, but I can't seem to get the LocaleData module.

Does anyone know how can I add a custom locale to use with datepicker?

Comment: You need to provide more information for people to be able to help you. Please share all code relevant to this question.

Comment: @Marventus there is no code to share. most of it is built-in into ngx-bootstrap. I just need to somehow add additional locale to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using Angular2 mydatepicker plugin. There you can easily define custom locales without any big hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mom for your project, you could do this:

### From the console/terminal:

```
npm install moment --save
```

### From your Angular Class:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```